# Integromat app {{connection.param}} not working

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am trying to setup an own App in Integromat

What is required for my App is an URL (and later a Bearer Token) to be entered manually by the user who wants to use my App.

I have the Apps Base:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "{{connection.url}}",
    "log": {
        "sanitize": ["request.headers.authorization"]
    }
}
```

a Connection:

Parameters:

```
[
    {
        "name": "url",
        "label": "url",
        "type": "text",
        "required": true,
        "value":"https://my-server"
    }
]
```

and the Scenario:

```
{
    "url": "/api/endpoint",
    "method": "GET",
    "qs": {},
    "headers": "{{connection.headers}}",
    "response": {
        "output": "{{body}}"
    }
}
```

When i execute, the scenario from my App. The URL seems not to be correctly taken over from the one configured inside the connection parametrs.

Can someone help?

Comment: Hi, This should work flawlessly, I just tried it on my custom app. Can you check if you have multiple connections that might have caused this issue? If you are still facing the issue, I can help you review this.

Comment: @Runcorn Hello, the issue is resolved, see Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was right. I had to delete the old Connection and create a new one.